# when I take a picture the image is not loading in the imageview

Tags: android, camera

I create a method to select a picture from the storage and when you select the picture, the image is loaded on the imageview, this one its working as expected, I have a problems with the second one, when i press the button the camera is loaded and I take the picture but when I press ok the imageview is not loading the image a took, let me paste you my code:

```
    private static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 2;
    private static final int CAMERA_INTENT = 3;



        mtomarBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intento = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intento, CAMERA_INTENT);
            }
        });
        mElegirFoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intento = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intento.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intento, GALLERY_INTENT);
            }
        });




@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT  && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            uri= data.getData();
            mImagenIv.setImageURI(uri);
        } else if(requestCode == CAMERA_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Bitmap  bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("Data");
            mImagenIv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
Bitmap  bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("Data");
```

with:

```
Bitmap  bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

The names of extras are case-senstitive.